# Mockito and PowerMock for ObjectInputStream

Tags: java, mocking, mockito, powermockito

I am trying to test a method that uses `ObjectInputStream` for reading in data from file but I want to use mocks for `ObjectInputStream`. This method to be tested instantiates a new `ObjectInputStream` every time it is called, so I need to use PowerMock for mocking the constructor so that everytime an `ObjectInputStream` is instantiated, it will be a mock. Here is what I have so far:

```
@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    ObjectInputStream inputStream = mock(ObjectInputStream.class);
    when(inputStream.readObject()).thenReturn(object);
    PowerMockito.whenNew(ObjectInputStream.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(inputStream);
    myFun() // call method to be tested   
}
```

However, this doesn't work for some reason as I get NullPointerException at `when(inputStream.readObject())`, which I don't know why. Any ideas on how to mock `ObjectInputStream`?

Comment: You don't have to mock everything. Pass a `ByteArrayOutputStream` to your method under test, then inspect its contents.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- The point is I don't change the method. Since the method instantiates a new InputStream within its body, I would need to mock the constructor.

Comment: But `ObjectInputStream` _wraps_ another underlying input stream.

Comment: I don't really need to mock the `ObjectInputStream` object per say, I just need to use PowerMock to ensure that everytime `new ObjectInputStream()` is called, a specific`ObjectInputStream` (perhaps predefined by me) is returned. Is this possible?

Comment: I very seriously doubt that your code is calling `new ObjectInputStream()`. Please provide the relevant section.

Comment: It is calling it like `new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(infile));` for a file. But this doesn't matter because to test I want to mock an input stream instead of using a real file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        Object object = mock(Object.class);
        ObjectInputStream inputStream = mock(ObjectInputStream.class);
        when(inputStream.readObject()).thenReturn(object);
        PowerMockito.whenNew(ObjectInputStream.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(inputStream);
        myFun() // call method to be tested   
    }
```

Did you create the object somewhere else?

And your test should assert against something?

Answer (score 0):

Your statement "This method to be tested instantiates a new ObjectInputStream every time it is called" implies that you could improve its testability. The disadvantage of coding to a concrete class is that you have a hidden dependency and need to resort to non-standard techniques for testing.

My recommendation is to see if you can expose the dependency. There are several ways to do this.

1. Pass your `ObjectInputStream` into the function rather than creating your own.
2. Add a `Function<ObjectInputStream,FileInputStream>` field to the class so you can mock the new instance without resorting to PowerMock.

Also consider if you can code to the `ObjectInput` interface rather than the concrete class.

If you take option 2. your test might then look something like:

```
ObjectInput mockObjectInput = mock(ObjectInput.class);
when(mockObjectInput.readObject()).thenReturn(object);    
ClassUnderTest testInstance = new ClassUnderTest(fis -> mockObjectInput);
testInstance.methodUnderTest();
verify...
```

In my view this would make your test more readable and the dependency more explicit.